# python alphanumeric sort gives No matching 'int(str)' overload found: Following overloads are available

Tags: python

```
data = set(['booklet', '4 sheets', '48 sheets', '12 sheets',44,443 ,'$sdsds', '>>>>ASdasdas'])
r = sorted(data, key=lambda item: (int(item.partition(' ')[0])
                                   if item[0].isdigit() else float('inf'), str(item)))
print ',\n'.join(r)
```

I got :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    r = sorted(data, key=lambda item: (int(item.partition(' ')[0])
  File "test.py", line 3, in <lambda>
    if item[0].isdigit() else float('inf'), str(item)))
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

How to make this sort working ?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Can you be specific please?

Comment: That's odd. I don't get SyntaxError, I get `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`. In any case, when `item` is 44, it doesn't make sense to call `partition` on it, or do `item[0]`, because it isn't a string.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be using Squish, would you?

Answer (score 2):

you want this???

```
In [12]: r = sorted(data, key=lambda item: (int(str(item).partition(' ')[0])if str(item)[0].isdigit() else float('inf'), str(item)))   

In [13]: r
Out[13]: 
['4 sheets',                                                                                                                           
 '12 sheets',                                                                                                                          
 44,                                                                                                                                   
 '48 sheets',                                                                                                                          
 443,                                                                                                                                  
 '$sdsds',                                                                                                                             
 '>>>>ASdasdas',                                                                                                                       
 'booklet']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't subscript an integer because they are not iterable. This is what you are trying to do when you do `44[0]`.

You might well have meant:

```
str(item)[0].isdigit()
```